# Laravel Eloqunt multiple select based on conditions

Tags: mysql, iphone, laravel

I could not find anyting about this, only with other Eloqunt stuff like the where functions. I did try some stuff but it didn't work.

So With Eloqunt you can do something like:

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', $id);
```

based on the user type I get from somewhere else I add a select

example:

```
switch($user_type) {
            case 10:
                $user->select('id',
                    'firstname',
                    'lastname',
                    'email',
                break;
            case 40:
                $user->select('id',
                    'firstname',
                    'lastname');
                    'email',
                    'someMoreFields', //etc
                break;

        }
```

And now based on some conditions I want to add more fields to the select something like.

```
if($someCondition) {
    $user->select('type');
}
```

But this results that the user object only returns the columns based on the last select('type') sadly. Does anyone know how to use multiple selects or a work around. Even pointing me to some documentation would be nice cause i could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use addSelect()

```
if($someCondition) {
    $user->addSelect('type');
}
```

or just build up the array you use in select():

```
$select = ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname'];

if($someCondition) {
    $select[] = 'type';
}

$user->select($select);
```

Comment: Perfect clean solutions. Love it! Thanks